how to create Mwaa/airflow dynamic sequentials tasks
I have a requirement to create a dynamic mwaa/airflow  which needs to create sequential tasks (not dynamic task mapping ) dynamically based on task list.
example1 : 
Task list =["task1","task2","task3"]
output = start>>task1>>task2>>task3>>end

example2 :
tasklist =["task1","task2"]
output=start>>task1>>task2>>end

appreciate if anyone can give a lead

The most straightforward way would be to use the built-in chain() function which create sequential task dependencies for you along with list unpacking.
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain

task_list = ["task1","task2","task3"]

chain(start, *task_list, end)


